# When creating an exception class should I implement all constructors of java.lang.Exception?

Tags: java, exception

When creating an exception class is it okay to only provide a "specific" constructor:

```
public CircularLinkException(final String msg, final String link)
{
    super(msg);
    link = inputName;
}
```

or should I implement the constructors of `Exception`:

```
public class CircularLinkException extends Exception
{
    public CircularLinkException() { /* ... */ }
    public CircularLinkException(final String msg) { /* ... */ }
    public CircularLinkException(final Throwable t) { /* ... */ }
    public CircularLinkException(final String msg, final Throwable t) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create all the Constructors you will use.

Don't add code when you imagine a use for something. Add it when you have a requirement for it.

http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html

Comment: That's true in general. However, in the case of exceptions, I usually implement the same constructors as the Exception class always if they don't need aditional parameters. _1. Create exception class. 2. Copy and paste constructors from any other exception class. 3. Rename the constructors for this class (by copying and pasting the name of the class)._ Implementing less constructors would only achieve saving a couple of seconds. It's worth doing it just in case I could need them later.

Comment: It's not so much about saving time as improving clarity of use and maintainability.  In this example the OP has an additional field. Should this field be `null` for the "inherited" constructors or should there be four constructors with this field.  Given there is no requirement for those constructors it's impossible to guess what is the right choice and later you might have to support both combinations depending on which one developers who use this class pick.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said _"if they don't need aditional parameters"_. I posted this as a comment and not as an answer because it could be useful to somebody, even if it doesn't apply to the OP specific case.

Comment: I see your point, but I would rather not have to guess whether additional parameters might be needed in the future. ;)

Comment: The additional parameter `link` must not be `null` in my case.

Comment: and what about the chaining of exceptions, that Audrius Meškauskas brings up in his answer?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Can this exception be triggered due to another exception or error?  If so you can make it the cause.  If it is not caused by another exception i.e. it's something you check for yourself, then you don't need to wrap another exception.  If it can only be triggered by another Exception, you can make this the only constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not actually **required** to implement any particular constructor. One arbitrary can be implemented in order to construct the exception at all.

Usually two cases happen:

- Your code realizes that something went wrong after checking something. It wants to raise exception. For such case, a constructor that takes a string message is required. It is usually good to explain in the message that went wrong.
- Your code tries to do something and catches exception that cannot be thrown further as it is not declared. Then you still can explain that went wrong in the message, put some important context data there, but also it is vital to provide that catched exception for diagnostic. For such case, you need a constructor that takes String and Throwable.

I think, the version without parameters and the version that takes Throwable only are more for lazy people and you just enforce more order in your code by not implementing these.

If your specific exception benefit from some additional information that is always  available, surely the constructor should have additional parameters, forcing to pass this information. In your case, a version with the two string parameters should be preserved but probably a version that also takes Throwable as a third parameter would be good. Many known exceptions (like IOException, for instance) went through the pain from "we will never need this kind of constructor" towards adding such constructor in the later versions.

Comment: I don't completely agree with your first point: forcing the caller to pass in the information about the circular link seems like a good design decision.

Comment: Forcing to pass more information is always a good design decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare only `specific` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to make your own exception

```
public class CircularLinkException extends Exception
```

so you can have arbitrary number of constructors for `CircularLinkException` but each of them should call `super(smthg)`, where it is one out of 4 from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to have all the constructor in your class. Create the constructor according to your need but keep in mind that Exception class in java does not have default constructor so always call the parent class constructor from the first line of the child class while making your own exception (Custom Exception).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html says it has a default constructor: `Exception()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to provide specific constructor and more constructors can be added as and when required. Personally I don't go for all the constructors from super class.

But it all depends on how the new Exception class "CircularLinkException" is going to be used. If this exception class is a part of some exception library which will be used by other users, then, may be, it is a good idea to provide "constructors from Exception class" + "new constructors". This way user has a option to choose between constructors depending on his needs.

If you are the only user of this exception class, then it is better to analyze which constructors are useful for your code and write those only. If you think that some constructors can be useful in future, you can always write them in the future :).